# Fetch senders locale - Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]I have app that replies to new messages to Facebook page. The app has all permissions required for messaging.

I need it to be able to communicate in users preferred language.

***Is there any way or permission to get senders locale?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Message Platform - User Profile API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

*This call can only be made with **valid user id** received through Send API. **Standard Facebook user id** does not work.*

Comment: This would require my app to be authorized by the sender. I'm authorized to access page not the person messaging the page.

Comment: So you can ask the permission when user accessing the app? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/open-graph-object-locale/

Comment: user is not accessing the app. User is messaging to a page which is administrated by the app. At the end of the day in most cases user doesn't know he/she is talking to  a bot

Comment: so your are using message bot api right? then you can access the locale as my first answer. You can use the `sender_id` of a user when your bot received the message to look up the user profile since your app has included an access token, thus you don't need any further authorisation from user.

Comment: This call: [uid]?fields=locale does not return specified users locale.           My access token permissions are: read_page_mailboxes, manage_pages, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, public_profile

Comment: so the User Profile API dose not work? can you show me why?   (I was saying to see my "answer" since you use the messenger bot API)

Comment: I was trying to use your answer :) All I got back was: first_name, last_name, id. I included a screen shot from graph API explorer in my question.

Comment: The app got positive review by Facebook approval team, so I got all required permissions I would assume :/ it's so frustrating. thanks for your help @iownthegame

Comment: is it possible that the person (Daniel) didn't set the locale and gender information on Facebook?

Comment: nope. It has to be set up and it's an account that I setup. Also this person message the page which is controlled by the app. Any chance, that you know what permissions are required to get all information specified in [User Profile API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile)?

Comment: In my case no other permissions needed. One thing to be mentioned, you should put the sender_id(which your bot received) as the USER_ID within the url, not the Facebook id of the user.